# Problems creating a buffer in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, compiler-errors, buffer

I have create a buffer structure like this:

```
template <typename T>
class locked_buffer {
public:
  locked_buffer(int n);
  locked_buffer(const locked_buffer &) = delete;
  ~locked_buffer() = default;

  int size() const noexcept;
  bool empty() const noexcept;
  bool full() const noexcept;

  void put(const T & x, bool last) noexcept;
  std::pair<bool,T> get() noexcept;

private:
  int next_position(int p) const noexcept;
  bool do_empty() const noexcept;
  bool do_full() const noexcept;

private:
  struct item {
    bool last;
    T value;
  };

  const int size_;
  std::unique_ptr<item[]> buf_;
  int next_read_ = 0;
  int next_write_ = 0;

  mutable std::mutex mut_;
  std::condition_variable not_full_;
  std::condition_variable not_empty_;
};

template <typename T>
locked_buffer<T>::locked_buffer(int n) :
  size_{n},
  buf_{new item[size_]}
{
}

template <typename T>
int locked_buffer<T>::size() const noexcept
{
  return size_;
}
```

But when I try to use it in my main function,

```
locked_buffer <std::pair<int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>>> buffer1;
```

I obtain an error like this:

```
error: missing template arguments before ‘std’ locked_buffer <std::pair<int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>>>buffer1;
```

I think is probably I'm not creating the template properly, but at this point I'm very frustated because I can't reach any proper solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing opening `<` after locked_buffer in declaration and in this case one more closing `>`.

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota After doing what you said, I got this error               `error: no matching function for call to ‘locked_buffer<std::pair<int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>>>::locked_buffer()’`
  `locked_buffer <std::pair<int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>>> buffer1;`

Comment: That is because this declaration is trying to call default constructor `locked_buffer()`... This is a bummer since in your class you do not allow for constructor with no arguments. Either make design change and add constructor with no arguments (or default int value), or create object using implemented constructor.

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota but I don't know exactly how the syntax is

Comment: Exactly the same as any other object in C++. `locked_buffer<type> buffer(3);` or do it with heap memory if you expect this buffer to get bigger (which seems like a possibility with vector<vector> type setting)

Answer (score 1):

As @TomaszPlaskota said, I created an object of type `locked_buffer` with n elements, where 'n' represents the size of the buffer that I'm creating.

```
locked_buffer <std::pair<int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>>> buffer1(n);
```